# If true, prove that 2 real numbers satisfy $a<b$ iff $a<b+ \epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon >0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I get that this is a biconditional statement, it holds in the forward direction since $\forall a<b$, $a<b+ \epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon>0$

In the reverse direction I get confused:

It seems to me that, for a contrapositive assume $a \geq b$, I can find some $\epsilon >0$ that makes $a<b+ \epsilon $.

Is this the way it works or am I still confused?

Thanks!!

Comment: Try $a = b$ and see if you think the conditions are equivalent.

Comment: @David, I can tell they are not equivalent that way, The $P \leftarrow Q$ implication fails that way, right?

Comment: Right.${{{{}}}}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This statement is not true. $a<b+\epsilon \ \ \forall \epsilon$ does not imply $a<b$. Take $a=b$, then $a<b+\epsilon \ \ \forall \epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

As David Kleiman points out the statement should be

$a \le b$ iff $a < b + \epsilon; \forall \epsilon > 0$

Forward (trivial): $a \le b < b + \epsilon$.

Reverse:

Suppose $a < b + \epsilon; \forall \epsilon > 0$.

Let $\delta = a - b$ then $b + \delta = b +a -b = a$ so $a \not < b + \delta$.  So $\delta \not > 0$.  So $\delta = a - b \le 0$.  So $a \le b$.